# What attribute to use that describes the link's destination for a social media icon set

Tags: html

Hi I'm getting an error regarding my social icon set links on my website, when I analyze my page for accessibility I get an error that states,

"73 links have no text describing their destination. Links have no text describing their destination. Links on a page should describe their destination for the benefit of both screen readers and search engine spiders.
Add meaningful anchor text that describes the link's destination. If the link contains an image, ensure you have provided alt text."

For design purpose I don't want static text displayed, only display the icons. How do I resolve this error. My code below

```
<ul class="list-inline">
    <li>
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/" target="_blank"> 
            <i class="livicon" data-name="facebook" data-size="18" data-loop="true" data-c="#ccc" data-hc="#ccc">
            </i>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it is title attribute
title="description"
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_title.asp

Comment: I tried that everywhere except in the <li title="facebook"> it works thank you